# Dynamic Vue components with sync and events

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'm using `<component v-for="...">` tags in Vue.js 2.3 to dynamically render a list of components.

The template looks like this:

```
<some-component v-for="{name, props}, index in modules" :key="index">
    <component :is="name" v-bind="props"></component>
</some-component>
```

The `modules` array is in my component `data()` here:

```
modules: [
    {
        name: 'some-thing',
        props: {
            color: '#0f0',
            text: 'some text',
        },
    },
    {
        name: 'some-thing',
        props: {
            color: '#f3f',
            text: 'some other text',
        },
    },
],
```

I'm using the `v-bind={...}` object syntax to dynamically bind props and this works perfectly. I also want to bind event listeners with `v-on` (and use `.sync`'d props) with this approach, but I don't know if it's possible without creating custom directives.

I tried adding to my `props` objects like this, but it didn't work:

```
props: {
    color: '#f3f',
    text: 'some other text',
    'v-on:loaded': 'handleLoaded', // no luck
    'volume.sync': 'someValue', // no luck
},
```

My goal is to let users re-order widgets in a sidebar with `vuedraggable`, and persist their layout preference to a database, but some of the widgets have `@event`s and `.sync`ed `prop`s. Is this possible? I welcome any suggestions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of a way you could accomplish this using a dynamic component. You could, however, do it with a render function.

Consider this data structure, which is a modification of yours.

```
modules: [
  {
    name: 'some-thing',
    props: {
      color: '#0f0',
      text: 'some text',
    },
    sync:{
      "volume": "volume"
    },
    on:{
      loaded: "handleLoaded"
    }
  },
  {
    name: 'other-thing',
    on:{
      clicked: "onClicked"
    }
  },
],
```

Here I am defining two other properties: `sync` and `on`. The `sync` property is an object that contains a list of all the properties you would want to `sync`. For example, above the `sync` property for one of the components contains `volume: "volume"`. That represents a property you would want to typically add as `:volume.sync="volume"`. There's no way (that I know of) that you can add that to your dynamic component dynamically, but in a render function, you could break it down into it's de-sugared parts and add a property and a handler for `updated:volume`.

Similarly with the `on` property, in a render function we can add a handler for an event identified by the key that calls a method identified in the value. Here is a possible implementation for that render function.

```
render(h){
  let components = []
  let modules = Object.assign({}, this.modules)
  for (let template of this.modules) {
    let def = {on:{}, props:{}}
    // add props
    if (template.props){
      def.props = template.props
    } 
    // add sync props
    if (template.sync){
      for (let sync of Object.keys(template.sync)){
        // sync properties are just sugar for a prop and a handler
        // for `updated:prop`. So here we add the prop and the handler.
        def.on[`update:${sync}`] = val => this[sync] = val
        def.props[sync] = this[template.sync[sync]]
      }
    }
    // add handers
    if (template.on){
      // for current purposes, the handler is a string containing the 
      // name of the method to call
      for (let handler of Object.keys(template.on)){
        def.on[handler] = this[template.on[handler]]
      }
    }
    components.push(h(template.name, def))
  }
  return h('div', components)
}
```

Basically, the render method looks through all the properties in your `template` in `modules` to decide how to render the component. In the case of properties, it just passes them along. For `sync` properties it breaks it down into the property and event handler, and for `on` handlers it adds the appropriate event handler.

Here is an example of this working.

```js
console.clear()

Vue.component("some-thing", {
  props: ["volume","text","color"],
  template: `
    <div>
     <span :style="{color}">{{text}}</span>
      <input :value="volume" @input="$emit('update:volume', $event.target.value)" />
      <button @click="$emit('loaded')">Click me</button>
    </div>
  `
})

Vue.component("other-thing", {
  template: `
    <div>
      <button @click="$emit('clicked')">Click me</button>
    </div>
  `
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    modules: [{
        name: 'some-thing',
        props: {
          color: '#0f0',
          text: 'some text',
        },
        sync: {
          "volume": "volume"
        },
        on: {
          loaded: "handleLoaded"
        }
      },
      {
        name: 'other-thing',
        on: {
          clicked: "onClicked"
        }
      },
    ],
    volume: "stuff"
  },
  methods: {
    handleLoaded() {
      alert('loaded')
    },
    onClicked() {
      alert("clicked")
    }
  },
  render(h) {
    let components = []
    let modules = Object.assign({}, this.modules)
    for (let template of this.modules) {
      let def = {
        on: {},
        props: {}
      }
      // add props
      if (template.props) {
        def.props = template.props
      }
      // add sync props
      if (template.sync) {
        for (let sync of Object.keys(template.sync)) {
          // sync properties are just sugar for a prop and a handler
          // for `updated:prop`. So here we add the prop and the handler.
          def.on[`update:${sync}`] = val => this[sync] = val
          def.props[sync] = this[template.sync[sync]]
        }
      }
      // add handers
      if (template.on) {
        // for current purposes, the handler is a string containing the 
        // name of the method to call
        for (let handler of Object.keys(template.on)) {
          def.on[handler] = this[template.on[handler]]
        }
      }
      components.push(h(template.name, def))
    }
    return h('div', components)
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.6/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I haven't done a custom render function before so I'll have a bunch of reading to do. It does seem like it makes more sense than a custom directive. I'll give it a try and see how it goes!

Comment: Thanks again, it looks like this definitely points me in the right direction. It technically answers my question, although I foresee some complications down the road. Since I intend to use it with `vuedraggable`, I'll be wrapping this custom-rendered component in `draggable`, but all of the variables, callbacks, etc. will be in the parent's scope. Any thoughts on how I can use them in a non-messy way? (Passing every single var as a discrete prop feels "messy" in this case, and I don't know how I'd handle events here). Any thoughts?

Comment: @DMack Passing multiple variables can be accomplished relatively easily by using `v-bind="someObject"` where `someObject` is an object where the keys are the properties of the component and the values are what you want to pass.

Comment: How about the `v-on` handlers, though? Is there some way to catch any event and just re-emit it to the parent?

Comment: @DMack Your structure is *parent -> draggable -> some-component -> other components*, and you want to pass events from *other-components -> parent*? That might be a case where you want to use a bus.

Comment: Originally I had parent->draggable->some-component, and the `draggable` and `component` tags were in the parent file so `parent`'s data/methods were all in scope. Now I've got it like parent->draggable->drag-list->some-component
(drag-list is this custom-rendered component above, and it wraps itself in `draggable` in the render function.) So the `method`s would be in the `drag-list` component file rather than the `parent` one... But you're right about an event bus, I was thinking about using an event bus / vuex to alleviate confusion from the start so I'll probably leverage that here.

Comment: If you want to do v-on passthrough, try v-on="$listeners".